# Client side validation for a password textbox value

Tags: asp.net, validation, client-side

I have a web form to submit a new user details. In that for password field, a textbox is used.
Validation is required for that as 'it shold contain min 8 characters with atleast one non-alphanumeric character'. I'm providing validation for it in web config file as:-

```
<membership defaultProvider="SQLMembershipProvider">
  <providers>
      <remove name="SQLMembershipProvider"/>
        <add name="SQLMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="DAFEConnection" minRequiredPasswordLength="8" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="1"   type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" applicationName="WBCPDA" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" enablePasswordReset="true" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="4" passwordAttemptWindow="15" requiresUniqueEmail="true"/>
            </providers>
        </membership>
```

This validation is triggered on server side, i.e. when I click 'submit' button.
I WANT TO VALIDATE THE SAME AT CLIENT-SIDE, i.e. as soon as he enters a non-desired value in text-box.

PLZ help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The quickest way to do this would be using a Regular Expression Validator. See [documentation here.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.regularexpressionvalidator.aspx)

Kangkan's suggestion is very good; not only the idea to use jQuery for this; but mostly the idea of using a regular expression to validate that the password is in the expected format.

**Additional answer:**

It's difficult The quickest way to give you exact code that will work for your case since you didn't provide markup; but you could do something similar to this :

```
<asp:button id="btnSubmit" runat="server" OnClientClick="return validate_pass();" OnClick="YourHandler" />
```

And would be using a javascript function .Regular Expression Validator. See documentation here.

```
function validate_pass()
{
    //txtPassword is assumed to be the id of the password text field on your page
    var passField = document.getElementById('<%=txtPassword.ClientID%>');
    if(passField.value.length<8)
    {  
       alert('Password must contain at least 8 characters');
       return false; 
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Icarus - Thnx for concern. But the soln u gave is to write my own custom validation to validate, client-side, password txt box. Actually, I want to implement client side validation in the in-built asp.net 'SqlMembershipProvider'. Is there a way?

Comment: @Kings: Well, yes, you coudl use a RegularExpressionValidator and attach it to your password field. Example here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.regularexpressionvalidator.aspx

Comment: lcarus: I guess its not possible to use that sql membership functionality to validate client side. The method u told is only possible and it is actually validation of password text box, not the membership password validation.

Comment: thnx anyways. plz post the previous code which u had. i ll use that for help. thnx

Answer (score 1):

You can use javascript or jQuery plugins to check for the password rules in the client side. You can refer to http://plugins.jquery.com/plugin-tags/password-validation or http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-password-validation/. You may even roll out your own javascript code and use RegEx to validate.